# AndroidStudio how to show java doc while hover EVEN method never used

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, javadoc

As title, I already set *Show quick documentation  on mouse move* ON.

Some of my method was set in public for other package called, when I hover it, the AndroidStudio just show me a stupid **Method 'xxxxxx() is never used'** message...

For now, it can only shown by press [control] + [space](on OSX), and I have to click anywhere other to dismiss it. I write java doc for every of my public method, so I'll check its result, press [control]+[space], click any other where, much much time.

I bet you can image how annoying it is......

Is that any way I can show a never used method's java doc directly ?

Answer (score 2):

Find the 'show quick documentation on mouse move' in preferences and chance the delay to something suitable for you.

[image]

Alternatively, you can press `F1` (on mac) to show javadoc for the currently focused item.  Because `ESC` is right next to this and will close the javadoc window, and mouseover windows generally get in the way, I find this is best one to get used to.  There's something nice about the fine-grained control it gives you.

You can also press `CMD+P` to show the names of parameters for the currently focused item, if applicable.